# M2Eclipse shows an error, but Maven compiles fine

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, m2eclipse

I always have some of the most obscure problems, and often I'll find similar problems but ones not applicable to my actual problem...

Anyways, I'm having an issue with M2Eclipse showing an error in Eclipse. Currently, my `POM.xml` references `xml-apis:xml-apis` of some version (yes, I'm aware of the issue with Xerces), and apparently, `xml-apis` replaces and not overrides classes in the JDK. One specific example of such is `org.w3c.dom.Element` in `rt.jar` in the JDK; this class exists, but `xml-apis` has a class with the same name and package structure, effectively replacing it -- or so Eclipse thinks.

What makes this bad for me is that since `xml-apis` replaces this implementation instead of overriding it, there are references in the code (which I've been tasked with migrating from Ant to Maven, where you could just change the build order and Eclipse would stop having a whinge) where the libraries to not match up... For example, `Element e; e.getTextContext();` would yield an error such that "`The method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Element`." This error only shows in the editor and the Problems window in Eclipse, though. But Maven compiles it just fine... So why is Eclipse showing an error?

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to change the build order in a Maven project in Eclipse to make it stop doing this. Does anyone have any solutions for this?

For reference (if it matters, which I doubt) I'm running Windows 7 Professional, compiling with JDK 1.6, and I'm using Maven 3.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select your project > right click > properties > java build path > order and export > select JRE entry and hit down
```

here you can control order of classpath entries, so if you want your jar from maven get picked up first move it to before JRE 's entry

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try this. Thanks! There is one discrepancy though, and that is that the maven dependencies should be after the JDK, apparently.

Comment: why it should be after JDK's entry ?

Comment: Beats me; I originally had it before the JDK and that was what was causing the error -- switching it to be after the JDK fixed it.

I'm sure there's some sort of mechanic with the compiler that notices that there's a class with a duplicate path/name and just takes the first one it found before the dupe.

Comment: tes first one gets picked up